# SQLite split column by integer versus character

Tags: sqlite

I have several data tables where the "SampleName" column has integer and character values.

I'd like to split that column into 2; `"Date" (int)` and `"SiteName" (Char)`.

Also - if there is a command function that can reorganize the `integers` into `date` values, this would be super helpful.
Any idea how to do this for multiple tables in one database?
Below is an example of the tables I'm looking at.

[image: example]

Answer (score 0):

Note that SQLite does not support a formal date type.  Instead, you can consider storing the date portion of the column as text, using text for the site name as well.  Assuming you already had a `Date` and `SiteName` column in your table you could try the following:

```
UPDATE yourTable
SET
    Date     = SUBSTR(SampleName, 1, 8),
    SiteName = SUBSTR(SampleName, 10, 3)
```

In most other databases, you could then also drop the `SampleName` column if it no longer served a purpose.  But this isn't possible in SQLite; the closest thing would be to drop the table and recreate it all over again withou the `SampleName` column.